# Kendo UI Detail Grid Hide Columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, grid, detailsview

I need a way to dynamically display/hide columns in the Kendo Detail Grid. I currently have a function that will hide columns of the Parent piece of the Kendo Grid, using the .hideColumn("ColName") function. 
Example:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

grid.hideColumn("Column1");
```

Is there a way to utilize the .hideColumns function to hide the columns of a Detail Grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. By using assiging the ID to the grid in the detailInit function, I can reference the child grid and use the .hideColumn function.

Declaration in detailInit function:

```
var detailGrid = $("<div id='detailGrid' />").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
...
});
```

Function:

```
var grid = $("#detailGrid").data("kendoGrid");    
grid.hideColumn("Column1");
```